# Custom LayoutManager for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to found out how to create a view like on the picture below. Are there any libraries to solve that use-case and if not, please navigate me what I have to do.
By now I found out that it's about LayoutManager.

Thank you in advance.

[image: mockup]

Comment: https://github.com/alibaba/UltraViewPager

Comment: try this one. =D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into a [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) with a `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` orientation as its parameter.

Another route could be using [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with custom paging animations.

Lastly, there is a library that seems to support exactly what you're looking for on [GitHub](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager) by combining the 2 approaches above.